# Dualshock 3 controller LEDs constantly flashing - Xubuntu 19.10

Tags: bluetooth, games, joystick

I have started using a original dualshock 3 controller on a upto date xubuntu 19.10 install via Bluetooth. Everything pairs via bluez manager gui and the controller works fine, but all 4 of the player LEDs constantly flash. The LEDs work as they should fine when connected via USB (P1 lights up continuously) and as far as I can tell the controllers identify themselves the same whether they are connected via BT or USB.

I have also tried using xboxdrv (it didn't find the controller) and qtsixad (from memory it wouldn't compile, but it also claims the whole by adapter for itself, which I can't do).

While I do not know if this worked as intended on previous version of Ubuntu, I have found a post on reddit which states that it did work on previous versions.

Anyone know how to fix all 4 lights from constantly flashing when connected via BT? Searching Google isn't giving me much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a kernel issue - After upgrading to 5.4.1 from the kernel PPA the lights work as they should on the controller. I am trying to work out how to post a bug on Launchpad and I will update this post when I do.

Bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1854618

Answer (score 1):

Playstation controllers are actually supported fully in kernel. But I have found same issues when using controllers on most desktop environments, because you have to allow pair & trust the device for it to connect with bluetooth automatically. I had no luck doing it through bluetoothctl and only way I could do it, was using KDE desktop and pairing it there(a pop up shows where you can click pair and trust device), then relogging to the other desktop environment. Every time you will want to use the controller, it will automatically connect unless you pair it back to your playstation.

Comment: Hi, I have zero issues pairing the controller and I am able to pair it in the Bluez GUI and use the controller is a non-desktop session (Kodi in its own session) without issue. Turn out the problem is in the kernel - see my answer below.